# make scrollbar as per theme in IE and Firefox

Tags: css

I'm working on this project: http://maithrigoonetilleke.com/
And I need some help fixing the scroll bar of the inner pages to be of the same colour in Chrome, Internet Explorer & Firefox.
but it only works on Chrome. In IE and Firefox it is same as default.

I used a custom css code to make the scrollbar look nicer:
**CSS**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 12px;
background-color: #3c3c3c;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
border-radius: 0px;
background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
border-radius: 0px;

background-color: #606060;
}
```

Check the link: http://maithrigoonetilleke.com/books/

Comment: follow this link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/674478/Customize-Scrollbars-using-CSS

Comment: hope it will help you http://almaer.com/blog/creating-custom-scrollbars-with-css-how-css-isnt-great-for-every-task

Answer (score 0):

CSS scrollbar customization is supported by Webkit-based browsers only. So, to customize scrollbars crossbrowser-way you should use javascript-based solution. There are lots of CSS customizable scrollbar plugins you can find in internet: jScrollPane, Malihu Custom Scrollbar, perfect-scrollbar and others. Try [jQuery Scrollbar](http://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) - this one is fully CSS customizable.